# LWUIT Calendar issue

Tags: java-me, calendar, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I am building a calendar in LWUIT, and I can´t find a way to solve the next problem.
When I add my calendar to the form, it shows a month `ComboBox`, a year `ComboBox` and the days of the  actual month with some days of the previous month and some days of the following month.
I don´t want to show the days of the previous month nor the days of the following month.

Can I set some UIID to them, to make them not visible?

Thanks.

Comment: You are right @jmunoz, the days from previous or next months dont have a different formatting or style from the days of the current month, while they previous and next month's date are not clickable. A visual style to differentiate them would be good or remove them totally from the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIID can't make a component invisible. We have a visible attribute (`setVisible(boolean)`), however an invisible component will still occupy the space where it resides.  If you want to completely remove the component just remove it from the parent container.

Comment: But i need to know how to get the days that I don´t want to show. In the LWUITDemo you called them CAlendar. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? Do you mean setUIID? We just the the UIID of a label in our calendar to any arbitrary value depending on its logical use.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog The point is to set different UIIDs to different parts of the Calendar component. We have seen in the sample application that you define styles for `CalendarDay`, `CalendarNavigation` and `CAlendarDay`. We just don't know how to map our Calendar instance with the different UIIDs.

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to derive Calendar and override updateButtonDayDate() and there you can set the UIID/viability to anything you would want.